# When I click clear button: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I create a user update page for my site. I added 'change image' section. It is works but when I click the "CLEAR" button I take this error:

```
ValueError at /user/update
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

I want when I click the "clear" button delete old image and assign default.jpg to new image.

----**OR**----

**How do I delete or hide "Clear" button in my site**

My Models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to ="profile_pics",
         null=True,blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.user.username} Profile"

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
      # super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

      img = Image.open(self.image.path)

      if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
          output_size = (300,300)
          img.thumbnail(output_size)
          img.save(self.image.path)
```

My forms:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
  email = forms.EmailField
  username = forms.CharField

  class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ["username", "email"]

      widgets = {
        "username": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control "}),
        "email": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control "}),

      }

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ["image"]
```

My signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.profile.save()
```

my Views:

```
def update_profile(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
      u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
      U_username = request.POST['username']
      U_email = request.POST['email']
      p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(
        request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
      userName = request.user
      # img = request.FILES["image"]
      # print(img)
      print(request.user)
     
      if U_email != request.user.email:
          if User.objects.filter(email=U_email).exists():
                print("warning")
                messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, "This email is already exist")            

      else:
          if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
               u_form.save()
               p_form.save()
               messages.add_message(
                   request, messages.SUCCESS, "Your account has been updated! ")
               userName = request.user
               return redirect("users",userName=userName)

  else:
    u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

  context = {
    'u_form': u_form,
    'p_form': p_form,
  }
  return render(request, "accounts/update.html", context)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

**MY TEMPLATE:**

```
{% extends 'fixed/_base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container my-5">
{% include 'fixed/_alert.html' %}
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <fieldset class="form-group">
           <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 h2">Update Profile</legend>
            {{ u_form | crispy }}
            {{ p_form | crispy }}
          </fieldset>
       <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block" 
             type="submit">Update</button>
       </div>
   </form>
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show your template Please (update.html)

Comment: I added template file

Answer (score 0):

In your project urls.py make sure you add the image memory holder.

````
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)```

This gives your media uploads a destination.
````